# Agda: How usual/curly braces are used relative to each other and to ':' sign

Tags: types, syntax, declaration, agda

I have trouble understanding this syntax. I didn't find the answer to my quesion in the Agda tutorial manual. The only thing I found was that `(x : A) -> (y : A) -> B` sugars to `(x : A)(y : A) -> B` which sugars into `(x y : A) -> B`, but this isn't the whole story.

What troubles me is that type declaration:

`map : {A B : Set} -> (A -> B) -> List A -> List B`

is fine, while

`map : {A B : Set} (A -> B) -> List A -> List B`

is not.

Version with arrow between arguments

`singleton : {A : Set} -> (x : A) → List A`

is fine, while the same expression without arrow

`singleton : {A : Set}(x : A) → List A`

is still fine.

The version with ':' between arguments

```
data _≡_  {a}{P : Set a} (x : P) : P → Set a where
  refl : x ≡ x
```

is fine, while

```
data _≡_ :  ∀{a}{P : Set a} (x : P) →  P → Set a where
  refl :  x ≡ x
```

is not.

In Haskell there is just regular braces, each separated with arrows. In Agda there is a lot more syntactic sugar, which isn't covered that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> while
>
> ```
> data _≡_ :  ∀{a}{P : Set a} (x : P) →  P → Set a where
>   refl :  x ≡ x
> ```
>
> is not.

This example parses fine; the error is from scope checking:

```
Not in scope:
  x at ...
when scope checking x
```

This error is beyond the scope of this question. As you seem to be noticing, though, there is a lot of similarity between your two putative definitions of `_≡_`: the `∀` symbol tells the parser that what follows should parse as a parameter list (like before the colon pertaining to the `_≡_`), but be understood as a list of Curried arguments. The main practical use of `∀` is to distinguish between `x → P x` and `∀ x → P x`. The former desugars to `(_ : x) → P x` (i.e, `x` is a type), while the latter desugars to `(x : _) → P x` (i.e, `x` stands for some individual, and its type is deduced from the type of `P`).

I think your other test cases can now mostly be worked out. The following doesn't have a sugared form because the `A → B` argument isn't given a name.

> What troubles me is that type declaration:
>
> ```
> map : {A B : Set} -> (A -> B) -> List A -> List B
> ```
>
> is fine, while
>
> ```
> map : {A B : Set} (A -> B) -> List A -> List B
> ```
>
> is not.

You could instead write:

```
 map : {A B : Set} (f : A -> B) -> List A -> List B
```

or

```
 map : {A B : Set} (_ : A -> B) -> List A -> List B
```

if you really wanted.

Comment: Could you please give a hint on what the difference between passing arguments before and after the colon sign is?

Comment: I think opening a separate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210237/agda-parameters-before-after-colon) was the right move.