# Agda. Parameters before/after colon

Tags: types, parameters, syntax, agda

When defining a data type, I can "pass" some parametrs before the colon.

```
data Image_э_  { A B : Set} : (f : A → B) →  B → Set where
   im : {f : A → B} → (x : A) → Image f э f x
```

But I seem to be unable to do this in function declarations for unknown reason.

```
exIm {A B : Set} : {f : A → B}{y : B} → Image f э y → B
exIm {y = y} _ = y
```

What is the fundamental difference between passing parameters before and after the colon? To be honest, I have no idea why would anyone want to pass parameters before colon and what advantages it can give. Maybe, such definitions of a data type makes the parameters before the colon visible in the constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have no idea why would anyone want to pass parameters before colon
> and what advantages it can give.

In a data type declaration parameters passed before the colon are in scope in
the body of the data type definition.

I think this would be a good feature request. We could have e.g.

```
typeOf {A : Set} : A -> Set
typeOf a = A -- A is in scope because `{A : Set}` was before the colon
```

So feel free to open a new issue suggesting the change: https://github.com/agda/agda/issues

Comment: I'd add: a big extra feature you get from left-of-colon indices on `data` definitions is that you can avoid size issues. Using left-of-colon indices, you can have `data Image_э_ {A B : Set} : (f : A → B) →  B → Set`, whereas the equivalent using purely right-of-colon indices would have to be `data Image_э_ : {A B : Set} (f : A → B) →  B → Set₁`, because the constructor stores the sets `A` and `B`.

Comment: @JamesWood Agda is now smart enough to detect parameters even if they're not left of the colon. So you don't get size issues in that one case.